# 403 Error while using AWS CodeCommit after being asked Username & Password (MacOS)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I've been using AWS CodeCommit for a while but currently having the following issue, have no idea what was the reason why it appeared:

1. After trying to run any git command, I get a dialog box, as I [have removed git-credential-osxkeychain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ch.html#troubleshooting-macoshttps) from the Keychain Access Control list. Pressing "Deny" (if not doing so, I get 403 immediately).
2. After pressing "Deny" it gives me

   ```
   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'secret_key'
   ```
3. Then it asks me for Username and Password

   ```
   Username for 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/somerepo': username
   Password for 'https://username@git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/somerepo':
   ```
4. After providing correct credentials here, I get an 403 error

   ```
   fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/somerepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
   ```

I've already tried to reinstall and reset both AWS CLI and Git credentials, have double-checked for possible solutions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html?shortFooter=true) and [also here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html), followed all the instructions, but nothing helped.

Please help me with some possible solution. Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: It means access denied. Are you sure you still have access?

Comment: Yes, I can access CodeCommit from the browser as usual.

Comment: Does `git config --list --show-origin` provide any useful information?

Comment: It looks like my issue is solved. I have reinstalled git entirely, and reset all the configurations. Not sure what exactly, but probably there was something wrong in my git configurations. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

> Step 1: Initial configuration for CodeCommit

> Step 2: Install Git

> Step 3: **Create Git credentials for HTTPS connections to CodeCommit**

> Step 4: Connect to the CodeCommit console and clone the repository

Steps 1 and 2 are common, but you may not be aware about step 3.

1. Go to the AWS console
2. Go to the IAM user that you are using to access codecommit from the CLI and generate username and password. (The URL looks like [https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/users/\](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/users/%5C)<userName>)
3. Then use this username and password when prompted on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051849/9387466), this can be caused by incorrect characters in your `~/.aws/credentials` file.

Answer (score -1):

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY as environment values solved my issue. I obtained these values creating an IAM Role with AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess & AWSCodeCommitFullAccess.