# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'secret_key'

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, secret-key

I got this error : **''NoneType' object has no attribute 'secret_key''** when I tried to update my application using **git pull**.I have already configured the AWS credentials at the following path : **nano /home/$USER/.aws/config** . I let it (the archive that I mentioned) as follows :

```
[profile eb-cli]
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<confidential>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<confidential>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question but i got the same here today. I had two profiles in `.aws/config` which used to work before.

However - Calling `aws configure` and enter the information's solved the issue form me. The command creates/modifies two separate files (config & credentials) in the .aws directory and it has added a `[default]` section, which i did not had before. I assume you can do this also manually and copy your existing profile block as default. Hope this helps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/index.html

Comment: just added default  to config file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an invalid `~/.aws/credentials` file. Double-check your profile names for any special characters or white-space etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user in IAM you used has or you're using the user HTTPS CodeCommit credentials.

see how to create [https codecommit credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Configure aws Profile

```
aws configure --profile myprofile
```

and add to Source Tree configaration

```
[credential "aws-repo-url"]
 helper = /opt/homebrew/bin/aws codecommit credential-helper --profile myprofile $@
 UseHttpPath = true
```